# How can I copy a file and update SQL database as a single transaction?

Tags: c#, database, file, transactions

My application needs to monitor a folder to incoming files and when it notices a new file has arrived, I need to copy it to another location and insert a record into a SQL database.

The problem is that these two actions are independent and do not succeed or fail together as a transaction.

Are there any options to solve this?

One option is to update SQL first and then copy the file and then update SQL and if it fails delete the file, but that delete operation can also fail causing both actions to become out of sync.

There is a system called Transactional NTFS but Microsoft recommends against using it.

Comment: Open a transaction over your sql connection, execute the update, if ok execute the copy, if ok commit the transaction. Everything else Rollback

Comment: You can do transactions in the filesystem without transactional NTFS, but not an out-of-the-box task.

Comment: If your file operation consist only in a single file copy then I don't understand why do you think it is necessary to have a 'transaction'. Can you explain?

Answer (score 0):

You should

1. Create a database transaction
2. Create the file system transaction
3. Do the database operations, without commiting the transaction
4. Do the file system operations
5. Commit the database transaction and the file system transaction if all ok, rollback both if something went wrong (r).

I would suggest checking this or something similar for the file system transaction http://transactionalfilemgr.codeplex.com/.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you need a transaction. You can monitor a folder for incoming files with a [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx). Once the file has been copied, perform the database operation.

**FileSystemWatcher Example**

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher;

private void Watch()
{
  watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
  watcher.Path = path;
  watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.LastAccess | NotifyFilters.LastWrite
                         | NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName;

  watcher.Filter = "*.*";
  watcher.Changed += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);
  watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
}

private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
   CopyFile(e.FullPath);
}

private void CopyFile(string fileNameAndPath)
{
   // copy file
   // make sure file exists at new  location
   // perform database operation
}
```